# Where can I find source codes of C++ library header files online?

Tags: c++

Is there a website that can make you look up c++ library **header** files' source codes online? Such as iostream, vector, map headers' source codes?

Comment: GOOGLE gave me this: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GitMirror

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ standard itself does not define anything related to implementation, especially when it comes to content of header files. It is totally implementation-specific.

- For `LLVM libc++`, you can look at [this page](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).
- In case of `GCC`, go to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) at GNU project.
- Microsoft Visual Studio (which includes `Visual C++` compiler) has built-in `CRT` (`C(++) Runtime`), that is located in `VS_INSTALL_FOLDER\VC\crt\src`.

But if you want to write portable, standard-compliant, multi-platform applications in C++, the only resource you should rely on is [functionality described by the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header), that should be present on every compiler, compatible with its particular version.

If you want to become a *real* C++ developer, you need to become a language-lawyer - someone, who produces code for *abstract machine*, described by the standard, not follower of specific implementation.

Platform-specific code should be used **only** in case of not-yet-standarized features or performance-critical sections, that often can be written more efficiently with OS-specific primitives.

Comment: There's still a lot you can learn from reading how library writers solve complex problems.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that is very true. I remember, that the most dynamic grow of my C++ skills happened, when I gained enough knowledge to read and understand `std` library headers. I am not advising no to do so. I only discourage relying on platform-specific macros, defines, names and functionality, which can change significantly between different versions.

Comment: Upvote for good explanation, un-upvote for the last sentence.

Comment: @immibis Yeah, I feel it makes this answer less pretty, than I intended it to be. Looks much more consistent now. Thanks for notice.

Comment: Do you really mean "effective" in the last sentence? Effective just means that "it works".

Comment: @KerrekSB No, I did **not** mean that, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout this [repo](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) for libc++